# Disable indentation folding strategy for a language in VScode

Tags: vscode-extensions

I'm developing a VScode extension that provides custom folds given a RegExp input. E.g. "show me all lines containing '----'. The extension also allows defining "line buffers" (or padding), e.g. "all lines, including 3 lines above a matching line and 4 lines below a matching line.

I'm using the registerFoldingRangeProvider to provide the desired folding ranges, and also dispose the previous provider when invoking a new folding command. However, the folding ranges of my custom extension seem to get merged with the suggestions of the default indentation based strategy (as described in the docs https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api), which frequently leads to unexpected results:

[image: fold-lines]

In the animation, I'm running the fold/filter command for all lines containing "----", with a top buffer of 3 lines and a bottom buffer of 4 lines. In my custom folding range provider, the following ranges are computed correctly:

[image]

However, as shown in the animation, these are not the regions that are eventually folded.
The code for the folding range provider can be found in this gist https://gist.github.com/chrispahm/1fb69c89eb6774d7c62ad131e3b57c41

The only explanation I have is that the results were merged with the indentation based folding provider. Is there a way that I can disable that provider, at least for a specific language? Or is there another bug that I'm failing to see here?